# replace text with bold if it matches with the given input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a requirement like when user enter text, bold the result string all matched substrings.

example : 'Test'

result should be : **Test** data from the data base, **test** data contain **TeSt** results

Comment: Search SO- this has been answered before.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide code snippet in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Since search and replace is not case sensitive we should use regular expression.

##### JavaScript

First thing is to `escapeRegExp` the word to search for so it can be used inside a regular expression. The second step is using `replace` which can refer to the matched string as first parameter in callback. So we replace with `'<b>' + $1 + '</b>'`.

```js
var sentence = "Test data from the data base, test data contain TeSt results";
var word = "Test";
var reg = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(word), "ig")
var result = sentence.replace(reg, function($1) {
  return "<b>" + $1 + "</b>";
});
document.write(result);

function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}
```

##### PHP

First thing is to `preg_quote` the word to search for so it can be used inside a regular expression. The second step is using `preg_replace` which can refer to the matched string as `$1`. So we replace with `<b>$1</b>`.

```php
$sentence = "Test data from the data base, test data contain TeSt results";
$word = "Test";
$reg = '/(' . preg_quote($word, '/') . ')/i';
$result = preg_replace($reg, "<b>$1</b>", $sentence);
echo $result;
```

Comment: I need to do it using JavaScript

Comment: when user give "search & data" as input won't work with the above  example. special characters are included in the search text, not highlighting in the output results

Comment: "search & data" -  What is the relevant input text?